# Calculate number a skipped items in a collection

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am working on an algorithm for computing all possible combinations of values in a set repeated $N$ times with an early evaluation trigger which terminates a series of combinations early

So, given $[0, 1, 2]$ and $N = 4$

I generate:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,1]
[0,0,1,2]
[...]
```

If I have a trigger for index $0$ and value 0, all combinations starting with 0 will be removed. My problem is how to compute the number of early terminated combinations?

Say for a set with $6$ values, repeated $10$ times the total possible combinations is $10^6=1,000,000$. If I find an illegal value at index $0 $I thought that would mean that I would skip $9^6=531,441$ possible combinations, but this can not be true, as $531,441 * 6 != 10^6$.
How do I calculate this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax command to take effect, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  A sequence of length $10$ with $6$ values has $6^{10} $ possibilities, not $10^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around.  You want $6^{10}$ and $6^9$.
Notice your list goes in groups of three rows, and there would be $3^4=81$ rows altogether, $27$ of which start with zero.

Comment: I see, thanks for correcting that. I still dont understand how to calculate skipped items, as $27*4 != 81$

Comment: 27 begin with 0, 27 begin with 1, 27 begin with 2, so there are three groups of 27 and 27×3=81

Comment: Thanks, when you spell it out it is obvious. Thanks for helping